# Batch to copy file from local pc to server

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, shutdown

I want to make a backup everytime i shut down the pc. I tried to add script to shutdown in gpedit but didn't worked properly. I tried also to create task in scheduler task. Also my script doesn't copy all the files in the folder, i don't know why.

Script:

```
SET hour=%time:~0,2%
IF "%hour:~0,1%"==" " SET hour=0%time:~1,1%
SET folder=%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%_%hour%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
md destination
XCOPY /s/e "source*.*" destination
```

Comment: For testing purposes I would use the full path for the source and destination.